# messy excel data with appended tables into r

Tags: r, excel

I have a public dataset in excel where column names both are repeated or changed every irregular number of rows, as is shown here:

| Industry and company size | NAICS code | Companies | United States | Alabama | Alaska | Arizona | Arkansas | California |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Manufacturing industries | 31–33 | 25408 | 159579 | 358 | D | 2442 | 166 | 35918 |
| Food | 311 | 1704 | 3659 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 40 | 152 |
| Beverage and tobacco products | 312 | 83 | 717 | * | D | * | * | 14 |
| Basic chemicals | 3251 | 416 | 1718 | 2 | 0 | * | 4 | 125 |
| … |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Industry and company size | NAICS code | Companies | United States | Alabama | Alaska | Arizona | Arkansas | California |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Other transportation | other 336 | 225 | 800 | 10 | * | D | * | 20 |
| Furniture and related products | 337 | 634 | 370 | 4 | * | 3 | * | 20 |
| Miscellaneous manufacturing | 339 | 3008 | 8097 | 5 | * | 65 | 4 | 2015 |
| Medical equipment and supplies |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| … |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Industry and company size | NAICS code | Colorado | Connecticut | Delaware | District of Columbia | Florida | Georgia | Hawaii |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| All industries | 21–23, 31–33, 42–81 | 3270 | 5482 | D | 84 | 3045 | 2931 | 173 |
| Manufacturing industries | 31–33 | 2344 | 5117 | D | 20 | 1697 | 1599 | 119 |
| Food | 311 | 43 | 9 | D | * | 16 | D | D |
| … |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Industry and company size | NAICS code | Colorado | Connecticut | Delaware | District of Columbia | Florida | Georgia | Hawaii |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Electromedical, electrotherapeutic, and irradiation apparatus | 334510, 334517 | 38 | 16 | 0 | 0 | 228 | 10 | * |
| Search, detection, navigation, guidance, aeronautical, and nautical system and instruments | 334511 | 62 | 20 | * | 0 | 91 | 18 | * |
| Other measuring and controlling instruments | other 3345 | 121 | 78 | 48 | 0 | 52 | 41 | D |

And so on, for all states. Here the ellipsis in the first column (...) represents more rows.

So, I need to take many excel files like this and create tidy tables like the following:

| Industry and company size | NAICS code | Companies | United States | Alabama | Alaska | Arizona | Arkansas | California | Colorado | Connecticut | Delaware | District of Columbia | Florida | Georgia | Hawaii |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Manufacturing industries | 31–33 | 25408 | 159579 | 358 | D | 2442 | 166 | 35918 | 3270 | 5482 | D | 84 | 3045 | 2931 | 173 |
| Food | 311 | 1704 | 3659 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 40 | 152 | 2344 | 5117 | D | 20 | 1697 | 1599 | 119 |
| Beverage and tobacco products | 312 | 83 | 717 | * | D | * | * | 14 | 43 | 9 | D | * | 16 | D | D |
| Basic chemicals | 3251 | 416 | 1718 | 2 | 0 | * | 4 | 125 | 38 | 16 | 0 | 0 | 228 | 10 | * |
| Other transportation | other 336 | 225 | 800 | 10 | * | D | * | 20 | 62 | 20 | * | 0 | 91 | 18 | * |
| Furniture and related products | 337 | 634 | 370 | 4 | * | 3 | * | 20 | 121 | 78 | 48 | 0 | 52 | 41 | D |
| Miscellaneous manufacturing | 339 | 3008 | 8097 | 5 | * | 65 | 4 | 2015 | 121 | 78 | 48 | 0 | 52 | 41 | D |
| Medical equipment and supplies |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| … |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I've been trying to find some examples for this case in the `unpivotr` and `tidyxl` packages, but unsuccessfully. I really appreciate any insights. Thanks!

EDITED:
The following is a chunk of the original dataset:

```
structure(list(`Industry and company size` = c(NA, "All industries", 
"Manufacturing industries", "Food", "Beverage and tobacco products", 
"Textiles, apparel, and leather products", "Wood products", "Paper", 
"Printing and related support activities", "Petroleum and coal products", 
"Chemicals", "Basic chemicals", "Resin, synthetic rubber, fibers, and filaments", 
"Pesticide, fertilizer, and other agricultural chemical", "Pharmaceuticals and medicines", 
"Soap, cleaning compound, and toilet preparation", "Paint, coating, adhesive, and other chemical", 
"Plastics and rubber products", "Nonmetallic mineral products", 
"Primary metals", "100–249", "250–499", "Medium and large companies (number of employees)", 
"500–999", "1,000–4,999", "5,000–9,999", "10,000–24,999", 
"25,000 or more", "Industry and company size", NA, "All industries", 
"Manufacturing industries", "Food", "Beverage and tobacco products", 
"Textiles, apparel, and leather products", "Wood products", "Paper", 
"Printing and related support activities", "Petroleum and coal products", 
"Chemicals", "Basic chemicals", "Resin, synthetic rubber, fibers, and filaments"
), `NAICS code` = c(NA, "21–23, 31–33, 42–81", "31–33", 
"311", "312", "313–316", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", 
"3251", "3252", "3253", "3254", "3256", "3255, 3259", "326", 
"327", "331", "–", "–", NA, "–", "–", "–", "–", "–", 
"NAICS code", NA, "21–23, 31–33, 42–81", "31–33", "311", 
"312", "313–316", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", "3251", 
"3252"), Companies = c(NA, "48393", "25408", "1704", "83", "1097", 
"255", "166", "637", "131", "3064", "416", "136", "37", "1471", 
"373", "631", "1253", "617", "226", "4516", "1551", NA, "794", 
"912", "187", "134", "105", "Colorado", NA, "3270", "2344", "43", 
"5", "*", "*", "*", "5", "10", "245", "22", "*"), ...4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "e", "e", "e", NA, NA, NA, NA, "e"), `United States` = c(NA, 
"221706", "159579", "3659", "717", "478", "229", "1247", "201", 
"1104", "53555", "1718", "807", "760", "45398", "2383", "2491", 
"1809", "1246", "579", "9435", "8413", NA, "8640", "39468", "21940", 
"36688", "74148", "Connecticut", NA, "5482", "5117", "9", "*", 
"D", "*", "D", "D", "D", "3690", "60", "3"), ...6 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "i", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "i", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "e", NA, "e", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Alabama = c(NA, "628", 
"358", "5", "*", "2", "4", "4", "*", "*", "89", "2", "3", "3", 
"80", "*", "2", "10", "2", "8", "73", "56", NA, "D", "187", "59", 
"26", "D", "Delaware", NA, "D", "D", "D", "D", "7", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "177", "7", "D"), ...8 = c(NA, NA, NA, "e", "e", "e", 
NA, NA, "e", "e", NA, "e", NA, NA, NA, "e", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "e", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Alaska = c(NA, "D", "D", "2", "D", "*", 
"D", "*", "*", "*", "*", "0", "0", "0", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", 
"*", "3", "D", NA, "D", "5", "*", "*", "1", "District of Columbia", 
NA, "84", "20", "*", "1", "*", "0", "0", "*", "0", "9", "0", 
"0"), ...10 = c(NA, NA, NA, "e", NA, "e", NA, "e", "e", "e", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "e", NA, "e", "e", "e", "e", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "e", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "e", NA, "e", "e", "e", 
"e", NA, NA, NA), Arizona = c(NA, "2841", "2442", "4", "*", "*", 
"*", "2", "1", "*", "153", "*", "*", "5", "116", "29", "2", "158", 
"1", "2", "69", "66", NA, "94", "437", "347", "198", "1352", 
"Florida", NA, "3045", "1697", "16", "3", "4", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "455", "7", "12"), ...12 = c(NA, NA, NA, "e", "e", "e", 
"e", NA, NA, "e", NA, "e", "e", "i", NA, NA, "e", NA, "e", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "e", 
NA, "e", NA, NA, NA, NA), Arkansas = c(NA, "245", "166", "40", 
"*", "*", "2", "D", "D", "D", "14", "4", "*", "3", "6", "1", 
"*", "5", "1", "6", "D", "D", NA, "D", "18", "34", "D", "D", 
"Georgia", NA, "2931", "1599", "D", "D", "D", "D", "84", "D", 
"D", "249", "40", "26"), ...14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "e", "e", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "e", NA, NA, NA, "e", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), California = c(NA, "53327", "35918", "152", 
"14", "70", "14", "19", "11", "72", "10050", "125", "5", "36", 
"9626", "171", "85", "97", "21", "12", "2422", "2469", NA, "2574", 
"11456", "6609", "9948", "12525", "Hawaii", NA, "173", "119", 
"D", "D", "*", "D", "D", "*", "2", "45", "0", "0"), ...16 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "i", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "e", NA, NA, "e", NA, "i", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you share both data entries with `dput` instead? All of the spaces make it challenging to read otherwise? Thanks.

Comment: Now I did it. Thanks for the advice @dcsuka

Answer (score 1):

A `cumsum`, `group_split`, and then simple filtering does the trick here. It generates a list of dataframes, if that is allright:

```r
df %>%
  group_split(new_df = cumsum(!is.na(`Industry and company size`)
                           & `Industry and company size` == "Industry and company size")) %>%
  map(~select(., -new_df) %>% filter(`Industry and company size` != "Industry and company size"))

# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 27 × 16
#    `Industry and company size`             `NAICS code`        Companies ...4  `United States` ...6  Alabama ...8  Alaska ...10 Arizona ...12 Arkansas ...14 California ...16
#    <chr>                                   <chr>               <chr>     <chr> <chr>           <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>      <chr>
#  1 All industries                          21–23, 31–33, 42–81 48393     NA    221706          NA    628     NA    D      NA    2841    NA    245      NA    53327      NA   
#  2 Manufacturing industries                31–33               25408     NA    159579          NA    358     NA    D      NA    2442    NA    166      NA    35918      NA   
#  3 Food                                    311                 1704      NA    3659            NA    5       e     2      e     4       e     40       NA    152        NA   
#  4 Beverage and tobacco products           312                 83        NA    717             NA    *       e     D      NA    *       e     *        e     14         NA   
#  5 Textiles, apparel, and leather products 313–316             1097      NA    478             NA    2       e     *      e     *       e     *        e     70         NA   
#  6 Wood products                           321                 255       NA    229             NA    4       NA    D      NA    *       e     2        NA    14         NA   
#  7 Paper                                   322                 166       NA    1247            NA    4       NA    *      e     2       NA    D        NA    19         NA   
#  8 Printing and related support activities 323                 637       NA    201             NA    *       e     *      e     1       NA    D        NA    11         NA   
#  9 Petroleum and coal products             324                 131       NA    1104            NA    *       e     *      e     *       e     D        NA    72         NA   
# 10 Chemicals                               325                 3064      NA    53555           NA    89      NA    *      NA    153     NA    14       NA    10050      NA   
# # … with 17 more rows
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 12 × 16
#    `Industry and company size`                    `NAICS code`        Companies ...4  `United States` ...6  Alabama ...8  Alaska ...10 Arizona ...12 Arkansas ...14 California ...16
#    <chr>                                          <chr>               <chr>     <chr> <chr>           <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>      <chr>
#  1 All industries                                 21–23, 31–33, 42–81 3270      NA    5482            NA    D       NA    84     NA    3045    NA    2931     NA    173        NA   
#  2 Manufacturing industries                       31–33               2344      NA    5117            NA    D       NA    20     NA    1697    NA    1599     NA    119        NA   
#  3 Food                                           311                 43        NA    9               NA    D       NA    *      NA    16      NA    D        NA    D          NA   
#  4 Beverage and tobacco products                  312                 5         NA    *               e     D       NA    1      e     3       NA    D        NA    D          NA   
#  5 Textiles, apparel, and leather products        313–316             *         e     D               NA    7       e     *      NA    4       NA    D        NA    *          e    
#  6 Wood products                                  321                 *         e     *               e     D       NA    0      e     1       e     D        NA    D          NA   
#  7 Paper                                          322                 *         e     D               NA    D       NA    0      e     1       NA    84       NA    D          NA   
#  8 Printing and related support activities        323                 5         NA    D               NA    D       NA    *      e     2       e     D        NA    *          e    
#  9 Petroleum and coal products                    324                 10        NA    D               NA    D       NA    0      e     1       NA    D        NA    2          NA   
# 10 Chemicals                                      325                 245       NA    3690            NA    177     NA    9      NA    455     NA    249      NA    45         i    
# 11 Basic chemicals                                3251                22        NA    60              NA    7       NA    0      NA    7       NA    40       NA    0          NA   
# 12 Resin, synthetic rubber, fibers, and filaments 3252                *         e     3               NA    D       NA    0      NA    12      NA    26       NA    0          NA
```